# how is bitcoin network protect itself from malicious nodes?

Tags: full-node, consensus

Can someone explain how does Bitcoin network protect itself from malicious nodes? Lets say someone creates bitcoin core clone and they manipulate it to their need. For example could someone change code for transaction verification? Or on a node lower mining difficulty? Could there be a slight change in consensus algorithm that goes undetected?